# How can I add hreflang links to the <head> in Zen Cart?

Tags: html, multilingual, hreflang, zen-cart

I have a site using Zen Cart platform. I made it in 6 languages. I am trying to improve my ranking and/or SEO and I wanted to insert `hreflang`  manually for each page.

I know that it should be inserted between `<head>` and `</head>` for each page, but whatever I tried - I cannot find **where** are `<head>` and `</head>` for each product.

Comment: Refer this [post](https://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?57812-Google-Verify-site-ownership&p=422467#post422467), since meta tags are also placed in head section. So it might help you. I think you should remove your site link, or your question will be close by moderator. I don't think site URL is necessary here. 

Well, that post code, will make same hreflang code on everypage, not to individual page. For individual, you have to use some condition code. Hope some zen cart expert will answer your question perfectly.

Comment: `hreflang` is an **attribute** that appears on **links** (most of which aren't in the `<head>`)

Comment: I know how you feel. I can't tell where `<head>` and `</head>` are either.

Comment: It appears that Zen Cart has hreflang links built in as of version 1.55a: https://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?214746-Implementing-hreflang-in-a-multilanguage-store&p=1319742#post1319742